# git push origin master fails and gives error: src refspec HEAD does not match any

Tags: git

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

I have git installed, and the ssh key setup, but I'm getting this weird error.

```
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop$ cd exercise/
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/exercise$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/admin/Desktop/exercise/.git/
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/exercise$ git remote add origin git@github.com:pavankat/exercise.git
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/exercise$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:pavankat/exercise.git'
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/exercise$ git push git@github.com:pavankat/exercise.git HEAD:test
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in /
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/exercise$ git push git@github.com:pavankat/exercise.git HEAD:test
error: src refspec HEAD does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:pavankat/exercise.git'
admin@Administrators-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/exercise$
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by pushing an empty repository to github?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

so i didn't do

```
git add .

git commit -am 'initial commit'
```

before I pushed.

:/

Comment: +1 after I googled this error already for the second time when pushin a fresh repo, always having forgotten the obligatory `git commit -m "initial commit"`.

Comment: This happened to me too, and that's because I copied and pasted the "push an existing repository code" XD.
Your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I faced below problem.

```
$ git push origin head:refs/for/<branch_name>
error: src refspec head does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/test'
```

Changing from 'head' to 'HEAD' solved the problem.

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch_name>
```

Though 'head' worked in other PCs, only 'HEAD' works in this particular PC.